# How to uninstall sample data with database from magento2?

Tags: magento2

Is there a way to remove sample data in Magento2 without uninstalling/re-installing Magento?

because I have changed settings in my back-end. and that I don't want to be removed.

But need to Remove all sample data also from back-end Like products categories  and customers Etc.

Comment: You'll have to roll sleeves and remove all sample data related information from your Admin and Database manually. Plan it well, before beginning, so to avoid chaos and confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this in the console `bin/magento sampledata:reset`

Please make sure take a backup of your db.

Enter the following command for remove:

`bin/magento sampledata:remove`

Wait while sample data is removed.

[For more See here.](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-sample-data-other.html)

Comment: it will only reset sample data , will not Remove from database 

It's only reset Command as you know also I have tried.

Comment: I have updated the answer also please visit on given link for more detail

Comment: yeah I have checked with command  "bin/magento sampledata:remove" It's working fine. but as you know It will remove sample data files from directory  and removed composer entries. But products and categories and attributes  will not Remove from magento backend.  Have you checked at your end  ??

Answer (score 0):

Not according to https://github.com/magento/magento2-sample-data which states that you need to drop the database and re-install.

`bin/magento sampledata:reset` will only add deleted sample data
and `bin/magento sampledata:remove` will only remove the sample data modules, not the database entities.